# How to use yaml template parameters in Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-prem?

Tags: azure-devops

According to the official documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops-2019 the Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-prem supports everything.

Yet, I cannot make it work with a simple yaml template with parameters.

Here is my yaml template (named prepare-sonar-qube.yml):

```
parameters:
- name: projectKey
  type: string

- name: projectName
  type: string
  default: ${{ parameters.projectKey }}

- name: useDotCover
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- template: install-java.yml

- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: 'Prepare SQ Analysis'
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarQube'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: parameters.projectKey
    projectName: parameters.projectName
    ${{ if parameters.useDotCover }}: 
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\coverage\*.CoverageResult.html
        sonar.inclusions=**/*.cs
    ${{ if !parameters.useDotCover }}: 
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\coverage\*.CoverageResult.xml 
        sonar.inclusions=**/*.cs
```

Here is the azure-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger:
- master

name: 1.0.$(Date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    demands: DotNetFramework
  workspace:
    clean: all
  variables:
  - template: variables.yml  
  steps:
  - template: prepare-sonar-qube.yml
    parameters:
      projectKey: logs2db

...
```

Running the build I get the following lovely error message:

```
/prepare-sonar-qube.yml (Line: 2, Col: 1): A sequence was not expected
```

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? (Besides being a loyal TFS customer who got stuck with an outdated on-prem Azure DevOps Server 2019 that does not seem to go anywhere when compared against the ever evolving hosted Azure DevOps Services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not did anything wrong. Need sorry to say, that is our document issue.

The syntax you are trying is our new `richer YAML syntax` feature, which haven't supported in Azure DevOps Server 2019 until now.

*To let public know and avoid this before we make changes to document, I create a thread and announce this unsupport [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/941173/facing-a-sequence-was-not-expected-when-applying-y.html).*

---

At present, the on-prem server only support the [older syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#template-references), where defaults are declared as a mapping **without** type or value constraints:

```
parameters:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
```

Or

```
parameters:
  solution: ''
```

Comment: How do I make one parameter default to the value of another parameter?

Comment: @mark, what do you mean of **default to the value of another parameter**?

Comment: If I want the parameter X to take the value of the parameter Y by default, i.e. when parameter X is not explicitly given.

Comment: @mark. If what you want is as your definition shared above, they are both in same template.yml file. Afraid to say, it does not support defined in `Parameters`. We haven't support compile A parameter's value then assign it to another parameter B( same in azure devops service).  You have to do this with tasks like command line and powershell.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a simple indentation issue.

Here's a snip from one of my working templates.

```
parameters:
  - name: sln
    type: string
    default: ''
  - name: slnName
    type: string
    default: ''
  - name: proj
    type: string
    default: ''
```

Try using `space` `space` `- name: [name]`

Comment: Does not work. Are you using the on-prem Azure DevOps Server ?

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of an old question now, but a similar question has been addressed in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175794/yaml-pipeline-doesnt-compile-parameter-unexpected-value-in-azure-devops-serv) that explains how using Runtime Parameters in Azure DevOps Server 2019 is not supported in that version.

If you try to review the [Runtime Parameters doc in MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2019&tabs=script), when you select the Azure DevOps Server 2019 option, it will show the warning that "*The requested page is not available for Azure DevOps Server 2019. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.*"

[image]