# Does Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-prem support yaml templates from another repository?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am going to start exactly the same as my other question ([How to use yaml template parameters in Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-prem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571976/how-to-use-yaml-template-parameters-in-azure-devops-server-2019-on-prem)) - According to the official documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops-2019 the Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-prem supports everything.

In particular, referencing yaml templates from another repository. However, trying to use it in practice fails with:

```
/azure-pipelines-common.yml: File /prepare-sonar-qube.yml not found in repository http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/DFDevOps/_git/logs2db branch refs/heads/master version 0ba42f59f36e74ad4fe39e59e4e8a3a56a6e9ff0.
```

[image]

Here is my yaml template:

```
trigger:
- master

name: 1.0.$(Date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.r)

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: NewProductTemplate
    ref: refs/heads/shelve/yaml-templates

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    demands: DotNetFramework
  workspace:
    clean: all
  variables:
  - template: variables.yml@templates
  steps:
  - template: azure-pipelines-common.yml
  - template: publish-nuget.yml@templates
  - template: publish-symbols.yml@templates
  - template: publish-code-coverage.yml@templates
  - template: promote-nuget.yml@templates
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this yet another case of misleading documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See statement `- template: azure-pipelines-common.yml`, it means you're referencing the template from **current** repos. The error message only indicates the `prepare-sonar-qube.yml` referenced by `azure-pipelines-common.yml` is missing in **master** branch of your **current** repos(`logs2db`?).

So if you define the reference to `prepare-sonar-qube.yml` like this in `azure-pipelines-common.yml`:

```
steps:
- template: prepare-sonar-qube.yml
```

You should make sure the `prepare-sonar-qube.yml` exists in where it current repos(`logs2db`) instead of another repos(`NewProductTemplate`). Or it's expected behavior to get errors like this:

[image]

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: I actually screw this up - referencing the yam template from repo does work after I fixed the problem you have identified.

Comment: Glad to know it helps :)