# YAML Pipeline doesn't compile Parameter: "Unexpected value" in Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-server-2019

My first post on here, forgive me if I am at all unclear. I am a junior developer, and completely new to YAML - it's very very likely I'm missing something that someone with more experience knows about!

I am attempting to build a YAML pipeline with one boolean parameter in Azure DevOps Server 2019. However, whenever I try to run my build, I get the error message: *"Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings. /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 18, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'parameters'"* My parameters themselves are flagged as an unexpected value. The compiler notes: *"Incorrect type. Expected "object"."* I can't figure out why this happens.

Sample of my code:

```
#VARIABLES
variables:
BuildPlatform: 'x64'
BuildConfiguration: 'release'

#PARAMETERS
parameters:
- name: 'MATLAB-upgrade'
displayName: 'Upgrade Matlab binaries'
type: boolean
default: false

#STEPS
steps:

#NUGET RESTORE
```

Note on my code: the indentation that I had in YAML isn't accurately represented here, can't figure out how to make the text editor work properly. My YAML indentation IRL is set up properly.

I don't understand what this means and the documentation isn't getting me anywhere either. From what I've seen it might have to do with schemas and templates, but I can't figure out how those concepts fit into ADO YAML pipelines. It might also have to do with the version I use, Azure DevOps Server 2019, maybe certain features aren't available there yet? My variables work fine.

Many thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings. /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 18, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'parameters'" My parameters themselves are flagged as an unexpected value. The compiler notes: "Incorrect type. Expected "object"."

I can reproduce the same issue in Azure DevOps Server 2019.

[image]

The root cause of this issue is that the Azure DevOps Server 2019 does not support the use of parameter.

In this doc: [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-2019), when you select the Azure DevOps Server 2019 option, it will show the warning.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this answer. I hadn't inferred that that notification meant that the functionality was not at all available, I just thought they posted it under one version... could be more clear from their end. Again many thanks!